# how to change embedded queries in excel when database moves/changes name

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a spreadsheet that contains embedded queries from an Access database.

The database name/location may move from time to time and I want to be able to easily update the queries to point to the new database. Having to change them manually may be difficult for other users.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the tables were created, you might try something on these lines. This updates the second connection in a workbook.

```
sCom = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).ODBCConnection.CommandText
sCon = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).ODBCConnection.Connection
db1 = "Z:\Docs\db1.mdb"
db2 = "Z:\Docs\db2.mdb"
sCom = Replace(sCom, db1, db2)
sCon = Replace(sCon, db1, db2)

ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).ODBCConnection.CommandText = sCom
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).ODBCConnection.Connection = sCon
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(2).Refresh
```